# How to lunch symfony command via shell script

Tags: shell, symfony, command

i have a symfony command that i want to lunch it from a shell script.

exemple: symfony mycommand.

i have a script shell figuring in the project folder and i'm passing to it the symfony command to execute as an argument.

the sh script:

```
time=$1
php_script_path=$2
log_file="script.log"

# Infinite loop
while true; do
    # Loop over the PHP script until the timeout is reached
    while timeout $time php $php_script_path; do
        # This code will only execute if the PHP script exits successfully within the timeout period
        echo "$(date): PHP script executed successfully" >> $log_file
    done

    # This code will only execute if the PHP script did not exit successfully within the timeout period
    if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
        echo "$(date): PHP script timed out" >> $log_file
    else
        echo "$(date): PHP script completed with an error" >> $log_file
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same as the cron command. Please set your project path in below PHP script.

```
time=$1
php_script_path="/var/www/project/bin/console app:your_command_name"
log_file="script.log"

# Infinite loop
while true; do
    # Loop over the PHP script until the timeout is reached
    while timeout $time php $php_script_path; do
        # This code will only execute if the PHP script exits successfully within the timeout period
        echo "$(date): PHP script executed successfully" >> $log_file
    done

    # This code will only execute if the PHP script did not exit successfully within the timeout period
    if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
        echo "$(date): PHP script timed out" >> $log_file
    else
        echo "$(date): PHP script completed with an error" >> $log_file
    fi
done
```

Comment: i dont want to do that because this script will be lunched in diffrent envirements / project paths

Comment: If different environments then definitely your project source is not there. Can you handle it by creating a new endpoint in the project and use in the bash script?

Comment: it works when i start the sh in the project without passing /var/www/project/bin/console in php_script_path

thank you for your replies @bhavin